# Add focus event on an element in a graph with jgraphx

Tags: java, graph, mxgraph, jgraphx, jgraph

I'm working with JGraphx in Java.
I have a BD with a huge ammount of elements, and I want to show in a graph just one node (the "origin") and its related ones to a certain order. 
The idea is to be able to "click" in one of these nodes, making this one the "new origin", but i can't find a event handler in the package.

Does it exist? Or do I have to modify the mxGraph package to add them in the JPanel and JFrame?

EDIT:
I found in the examples a MouseAdapter implementation that can do what I want, getting the cell at the (X,Y) position with the mouseClicked event.
Is better than nothing, but I still want to know if there is some focus event handler.